# Mathematic symbols in answer

Tags: support

I wanted to refer to refer to this [this link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1160/39834) as an answer to [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/how-strong-is-monero-cryptography-against-brute-force-attacks), and copy/paste its content for the ease of use.

However, the format of math symbols does not work on this site. 
There is a section "MathJax Help" in the cryptography site that is not present in this site.

So my question is : how can i show the content of the link in this site ?
Can someone activate MathJax for this site ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should reconsider this when there is a broader need. For now, it's pretty convinient to just use external tools. Also see this heavy debate on main meta: [LaTeX on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow)

For now, try this:

```
http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?Monero\cdot\frac{Stack}{Exchange}
```

Result:

[image: Monero Stack Exchange]

Play around here: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php